# How to write multiple enums data to the single pojo and return it as list

Tags: java, java-8, enums

is there a way using java 8 feature to convert multiple eums data to single pojo and return it as list.
I am trying this because i have scenario in application to return thedrop down values from enums from backend.

```
public enum TransactionTypeStatuses {
    NEW("NEW"),
    ACTIVE("ACTV"),

    String code;

    TransactionTypeStatuses(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String code() {
        return code;
    }
}

public enum MemberTypes {

    CENTRAL_BANK("MB01"),
    DIRECT_PARTICIPANT("MB02");

    private String code;
    private  MemberTypes(String code) {
        this.code =code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}


public class EnumDataPojo {
    private  String id;
    private String description;

   //setters and getters
}
```

Add the enums data to the pojo and convert the pojo to the json response

```
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        List<EnumDataPojo> response = convertEnumsToPojo(); //contains the data of All enums in "id" and "desscription" format
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String response = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(data);
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    stiatic List<EnumDataPojo> convertEnumsToPojo(){

            List<EnumDataPojo> dataList = new ArrayList<>(); 

            for(TransactionTypeStatuses enum1: TransactionTypeStatuses.values())
            { 
                EnumDataPojo data1 = new EnumDataPojo (); 
                data1.setID(enum1.getCode());
                data1.setdescription(String.value(enum1)); 
                dataList.add(data1);
            }

            for(MemberTypes enum2: MemberTypes.values())
            { 
                EnumDataPojo data2 = new EnumDataPojo (); 
                data2.setID(enum2.getCode());
                data2.setdescription(String.value(enum2)); 
                dataList.add(data2);
            }

            return dataList;

    }

}
```

json response from the above code

```
{
    "transactionTypeStatuses":[ //enum
      {
         "id":"NEW",
         "description":"New"
      },
       {
          "id":"ACTV",
          "description":"active"
       }
    ],

 "memberTypes":[  //enum
      { "id": "MB01", "description": "Central Bank" },
      { "id": "MB02", "description": "Direct Participant" }
    ]

}
```

Updated answer

```
public class EnumDataValues{
   private String id;
   private String description;
//getters and setters


}
```

//convert each enum to pojo and put it in list.

```
private List<EnumDataValues> getEnumReferenceData(Class<?> c) {
            List<EnumDataValues> referenceDataList = new ArrayList<>();
            List enumConstants = Arrays.asList(c.getEnumConstants());
            if (!enumConstants.isEmpty()) {
                enumConstants.forEach(t -> {
                    EnumDataValues referenceData = new EnumDataValues();
                    referenceData.setId(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(t)));
                    referenceData.setDescription(String.valueOf(t));
                    referenceDataList.add(referenceData);
                });
            }
            return referenceDataList;
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are setting same object in loop

Comment: @Eklavya i have edited tot he actual object

Comment: Your are setting data1 in every iteration of loop then you will get only 1 data per   enum

Comment: private List<ReferenceData> getEnumReferenceData(Class<?> c) {
  List<ReferenceData> referenceDataList = new ArrayList<>();
  List enumConstants = Arrays.asList(c.getEnumConstants());
  if (!enumConstants.isEmpty()) {
   enumConstants.forEach(t -> {
    ReferenceData referenceData = new ReferenceData();
    referenceData.setId(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(t)));
    referenceData.setDescription(String.valueOf(t));
    referenceDataList.add(referenceData);
   });
  }
  return referenceDataList;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code will give you correct response. You should add data in loop to get all values of each enums

```
List<EnumDataValues> enum1DataList = new ArrayList<>(); 
for(Enum1 enum1: enum1.values()){ 
     EnumDataValues data1 = new EnumDataValues (); 
     data1.setID(enum1.getCode());
     data1.setdescription(String.value(enum1)); 
     dataList.add(data1);
}
```

Do same for other enums

**Update:**

Use `Map<String, List<EnumDataValues>>` as response type and set the enum data.

```
Map<String, List<EnumDataValues>> convertEnumsToPojo(){

        List<EnumDataPojo> dataList = new ArrayList<>(); 

        for(TransactionTypeStatuses enum1: TransactionTypeStatuses.values())
        { 
            EnumDataPojo data1 = new EnumDataPojo (); 
            data1.setID(enum1.getCode());
            data1.setdescription(String.value(enum1)); 
            dataList.add(data1);
        }
        List<EnumDataPojo> dataList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(MemberTypes enum2: MemberTypes.values())
        { 
            EnumDataPojo data2 = new EnumDataPojo (); 
            data2.setID(enum2.getCode());
            data2.setdescription(String.value(enum2)); 
            dataList2.add(data2);
        }
        Map<String, List<EnumDataValues>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("transactionTypeStatuses", enum1DataList);
        map.put("memberTypes", enum2DataList);
        return map;
}
```

Comment: What i was lookign is instead of writing loop for each enum trying to maintain enumList (Enum1 ,Enum2..) and then iterate through each Enum and assign values to pojo.
can you suggest if any approach.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. I am giving you solution for your response body. Try to clear your question, and show how you want your response.

Comment: apologies confusion .
Edited and hope it is clear  now.

Comment: using ObjectMapper to test the response alone.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: That Was useful i just made small change on top of it Instead of writing loops for each enums i have made changed it to generic method which will handle the enums conversion to pojo by looping through the each enum

Comment: private List<EnumData> getEnumReferenceData(Class<?> c) {
  List<ReferenceData> referenceDataList = new ArrayList<>();
  List enumConstants = Arrays.asList(c.getEnumConstants());
  if (!enumConstants.isEmpty()) {
   enumConstants.forEach(t -> {
    ReferenceData referenceData = new ReferenceData();
    referenceData.setId(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(t)));
    referenceData.setDescription(String.valueOf(t));
    referenceDataList.add(referenceData);
   });
  }
  return referenceDataList;
 }

Comment: @raju You can post as an answer.

Comment: Posted .Thank you